# Unpack a flattened hash into Hash/JSON

Tags: ruby, json, hash-map

The following JSON

```json
{
    "a": {
            "b": {
                    "c":{
                            "d": [
                                    {
                                        "e": {
                                            "m": "n"
                                        },
                                        "f": ["p","q","r"]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "g": {
                                            "x": "y",
                                            "u": "v"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                        },
                    "h": {
                        "s": "t"
                    },
                    "i": ["1","2","3"]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

has been flattened, so that the depth is only 1 and the leaf nodes are values to the flattened keys that represent the depth, like

```rb
{
    "a.b.c.d.0.e" => {"m" => "n"},
    "a.b.h" => {"s" => "t"},
    "a.b.c.d.0.f.1" => "q",
    "a.b.c.d.0.f.0" => "p",
    "a.b.c.d.0.f.2" => "r",
    "a.b.c.d.1.g" => {"x" => "y", "u" => "v"},
    "a.b.i.0" => "1",
    "a.b.i.1" => "2",
    "a.b.i.2" => "3"
}
```

Now this is my input and I would need to reconstruct from this flattened hash the original nested structure. I have written following function to reconstruct into a Hash.

```rb
def unpack_to_json(hash, keys)
    j_son = {}
    keys.each { |key|
        j = j_son
        # break the key into elements
        li = key.split('.')
        le = li.length()
        li.each_with_index { |el, i|
            
            # check if final element
            if i+1 == le
                if el.to_i.to_s == el
                    hash[key].is_a?(String) ? j[el.to_i] =  hash[key] : j[el.to_i] = j[el.to_i].merge(hash[key])
                else
                    j[el] = hash[key]
                end
            elsif el.to_i.to_s == el
                if !j[el.to_i].nil?
                    j = j[el.to_i]
                else
                    j[el.to_i] = {}
                    j = j[el.to_i]
                end
            else
                if !j[el].nil?
                    j = j[el]
                elsif li[i+1].to_i.to_s == li[i+1]
                    j[el] = []
                    j = j[el]
                else
                    j[el] = {}
                    j = j[el]
                end
            end
        }
        # pp j_son
    }
    return j_son
end
```

It's crude but works. Can it be better?